# How to edit existing image using Carrierwave and MiniMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

Say I have:

```
Class Image < ApplicationRecord
  require 'carrierwave'
  mount_uploader :specialup, SpecialupUploader

  ...methods...

  def crop
    require 'mini_magick'
    ...some code...
  end

  ...methods...

end
```

Carrierwave uses Minimagick too and modifies its commands in some way that causes bugs in all other places that are not connected with carrierwave.

If you're intrested in specifics (and to help others to find this question in future): Carrierwave adds option -specialup(uploader's name) to all the minimagick commands (which base on mogrify). So Mogrify rolls out error messages like:

```
`mogrify: unrecognized option '-specialup' @ error/mogrify` and so on
```

I tried to reload minimagick with `require 'mini_magick'` in the method's body but there's no result. Also tried `load 'mini_magick'` - the same.

I can't figure out how to make it right!

Comment: Just curious. Why do you need `mogrify` here? Why not just do the cropping task using the normal Carrierwave + MiniMagick way? 

Comment: `specialup` is your column name, it's strange that it appears as a cmd arg. Did you do some thing special within your uploader?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin Minimagick uses mogrify for its operations. What 'normal way' do you suggest for cropping an existing image with position and size params sent by a user?

Comment: @a-ta-ta https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltoPZEzmtJA

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin Thanks a lot!